Use Go runtime with -buildmode=c-archive
Is it possible to have Go code use the Go runtime with this buildmode?
-buildmode=c-archive
I am building my Go code as a static library and linking it with .o files that were compiled from native assembly code. The project launches in the assembly code and calls into the Go code. Then the Go code starts executing in runtime.rt0_go to start the process of initializing the runtime.
Near the end of runtime.main in the proc.go file, the code exits the Go runtime before running main.main. Since isarchive is true we just return out of runtime.main.
    if isarchive || islibrary {
        return
    }

    fn := main_main
    fn() 

So, I'm wondering if it's possible to use Go runtime features when compiling as an archive file. If it is, I think I may be using the wrong method to accomplish my goal.

No, having multiple runtimes in the same binary is not supported and may fail in strange ways.

@JimB Without me manually entering runtime.rt0_go, is there already a runtime associated with the Go archive?

yes, because you can't really run Go without the Go runtime, and c-archive is intended to be loaded in a non-Go context. Normal use of  network, file IO, goroutines, timers, garbage collection, etc. all require the runtime. That is just skipping the main function call.

I see, thanks for elaborating! I may have a weirder environment and I don't know if it makes a difference. Prior to calling runtime.rt0_go, all of the Go does not use code that requires the runtime. For example, it uses things like static arrays and functions use the //go:nosplit directive. With that setup do you think that would work and just be a single runtime instance? If not, it's all good, I just wanted to give a little more information.

I don't know. I would assume the runtime is started on first initialization, since it doesn't know what code may be called later. Regardless, depending on any of this is limited to a specific go version, on a specific OS and architecture, none of which is specified.

This method of using Go runtime features in Go code is viable. I learned that isarchive can be modified with Go assembly. I did this before calling runtime.rt0_go.
The Go assembly to change isarchive looks like this:
MOVD    $0,     R0
MOVB    R0,     runtime·isarchive(SB)

Since isarchive is now 0, the code enters main.main.
